# spark read json stuck on load file upper 1G

Tags: pyspark

when I try to load a JSON file upper from 1G, the process run forever without throw any exception.

```
dump=spark.read.json("hdfs://ip-000-00-0-000.aws.foobar.com:8020/user/hadoop/mixpanel-event2017-12-11a2.txt")
```

I am using:
Spark - 2.0.2,
Master - m4.4xlarge
Core - 4m4.4xlarge
Run on Pyspark

Answer (score 0):

That sounds that you need more memory. (Spark default driver memory is 1G)

Comment: I run it with spark.driver.memory=4G

Comment: Any other suggestion?